# reading from a list and print host name is open on specific port

Tags: linux, bash, nmap

I wrote  `nmap command` like:

```
nmap -oX test.xml -p 23 -il list.txt > out.txt
```

how can I tell nmap to print hosts from my list.txt which are open on port 23?

Comment: from the man page (and intution) `-p <port ranges>: Only scan specified ports`. It looks like the command you have constructed is doing exactly what you want. Consider editing your question with example output, and required out so we can see the difference. Do you really need XML output!? Alex's solutions looks good to me. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't ask nmap to just print them, but you can grep nmap results:

```
nmap -p 23 -i list.txt | grep '^23.*open' -B3 | grep '^Nmap scan' | cut -d\( -f2 | cut -d\) -f1
```